# bootstrap carousel not starting

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having wired issue with bootstrap carousel, which is not starting automatically but it will start when user click on the next /previous arrow and continue the rotation.

I tried several solution suggested in this forum, but no luck yet. Anyone had the same issue and got fixed?

Comment: can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: I haven't change anything on bootstrap JS or CSS, basically the classes used are the same and haven't overridden any classes. I'm thinking of any other JS  libraries causing the issue.

I have used, Jquery, jQuery UI and shadowbox .

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you you need to reproduce your problem with the minimal amount of code possible as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Here your answer and [live view](http://codepen.io/ashikjs/full/Wxrypk/)

```css
 .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
}

.item img {
  height: 400px !important
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Goole.jpg" alt="Chania 1" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://peterwardhomes.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/goole-area-shot_005.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/Destinations/Europe/France/Nice/Nice-nightlife-coastline-xlarge.jpg" alt="Flower 1" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01858/nice3_1858695b.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://eastriding.limehouse.co.uk/events/21318/images/highresRGB/2376387_0_1.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the change you have made to start the carousal automatically?

Comment: Nothing Change, that's the reason we need your code. @NPN

Comment: good try it .... You can take a help from here [carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)